# Compare 3 random numbers goes wrong

Tags: random, compare, slot

I'm a total rookie and I'm trying to write a simple code that compares 3 random numbers for a slot machine type game.
In this case only between 1 and 3 since I'm encountering a problem.
It seems that only the combinations of 1,1,1 and 2,2,1 and 3,3,1 win.
Does anybody understand why 2,2,1 and 3,3,1 are winning and 2,2,2 and 3,3,3 do not?

```
let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
let num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);

function guess(){
 console.log(num1, num2, num3)
 if(num1==num2==num3){
  console.log('JACKPOT!');
 } 
 else{
 console.log('try again');
 }
}

guess()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not JS enthusiast, but I think it would be better if you compare the 3 numbers in a different way like that for example:

```
num1==num2 && num2==num3
```

I think that in your code works even if just num1 and num2 compare goes well

Comment: That did it! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

It is because when using a==b==c you are using booblean algebra, so 1==1 is true and true==1 will be true, when evaluating you will end up with only 1 1 1 working or 1 1 X working or 1 2 2 working. If going to use booblean algebra you have to evaluate true = true & true = true, the AND will evaluate that if in the left side is true AND the right side is true then JACKPOT.

```js
function guess(){
let num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
let num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
let num3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
console.log(num1, num2, num3)
 if(num1==num2&&num2==num3){
  console.log('JACKPOT!');
 } 
 else{
 console.log('try again');
 }
}

guess()
```

Comment: Aha I get it, thanks for the clear explanation!